# How can I use MFMailComposeViewController for my custom messaging

Tags: ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I need to implement a functionality where I want to allow user to share app content through email, but we need to send the email from server and not using the device configured email.

My question is, is it possible to use MFMailComposeViewController and get the Send button handler without actually allowing the composer to send the email?

Comment: if what's important to you is the destination email addresses and you don't want the user to add text to the email body , why you don't send the addresses to the server using http ? then send the email from the server !

Comment: I want user to enter/edit the preset text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this behaviour is wanted by apple.
I would implement a form and submit this form to the your server and generate a email on your server.
I think the amount of time spended to hack the MFMailComposeViewController is more than the time to implement your own email form.

Comment: yeah I kind of agree with you, but was feeling too lazy to develop a custom form.  Moreover I wanted the integration of stock iOS form with the Address book.

Comment: I would develop a custom TableViewController and style it like the MFMailComposeViewController, that's much more likely.

Comment: It seems from your answer that there is no support for it.  Thanks, thats what I wanted to confirm.